# How do I remove portions of a file name from ArcGIS Shapefile?

Tags: python, arcgis

I created several shapefiles from various KMZ files using Global Mapper. The output name looks like this:

"AllLines_P__1035_-_600_Mile_FlightLine_ABC_Flight_Plans_Line_94.kml.shp"

I want to remove everything except for "Line_94.shp" of the file name in ArcGIS.

Is there a python script or tool I can use to remove this excess naming from over 100 files? All files have identical naming except for the line number.

Thank you!

Comment: you mean to rename each file to Line_??.shp

Comment: You'll find ArcPy Q&As on this at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are sure that all will be identical except for `Line_94` i.e the line number

A simple

`len('AllLines_P__1035_-_600_Mile_FlightLine_ABC_Flight_Plans_')`

Gives us that there are 56 characters before that `Line_94` i.e the line number.

So you want from the 57th character. So simply use `slicing` to slice all 56 characters. `0` to `55` will be removed and characters from `56` will be printed.

**NOTE:** Index start from `0`. So removing `56` characters means removing all till index `55`.

```
s1 = 'AllLines_P__1035_-_600_Mile_FlightLine_ABC_Flight_Plans_Line_94.kml.shp'
s2 = 'AllLines_P__1035_-_600_Mile_FlightLine_ABC_Flight_Plans_Line_12.kml.shp'
s3 = 'AllLines_P__1035_-_600_Mile_FlightLine_ABC_Flight_Plans_Line_2.kml.shp'
print(s1[56:])
print(s2[56:])
print(s3[56:])
```

output:

```
Line_94.kml.shp
Line_12.kml.shp
Line_2.kml.shp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os

for oldname in glob.glob('AllLines*'):
    newname=oldname.replace('.kml','').replace('AllLines_P__1035_-_600_Mile_FlightLine_ABC_Flight_Plans_','')
    os.rename(oldname,newname)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob

def split_string(s):
    ln,ext=s.split('_')[-2:]
    ext='.'.join([ext.split('.')[0],ext.split('.')[2]])
    return '_'.join([ln,ext])
```

if you just want names then

```
renamed_strs=[split_string(s) for s in glob.glob('*.shp')]
```

if you want to rename all files then

```
from subprocess import call

for s in glob.glob('*.php'):
    call(["mv",s,split_string(s)])
```

if you are on windows you could use `move` instead of `mv` in call function.
if your files span multiple directories check `os.walk()` function

Comment: Why use `subprocess.call` instead of `os.rename`?

Comment: right may be better in this case! i like subprocess , can do multiple things at a time.